# What is this song from this youtube video?

Tags: identify-this-song, pop, japan

What is this song in this YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RcW3-3W3Xw ?

The title of the video is "【手描きHQ】飛雄と及川で威../風.堂/".

Someone said commented that it is Pomp and Circumstance, but I can neither find the original recording nor the original artist of this song.

Each time I use Google or Bing, I keep getting covers and graduation stuff, and this song definitely does not play at graduation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments under the YT video suggest that the 2 characters
are from a (volleyball-themed) manga/anime series called Haikyuu, and that the song's Romaji 
title is " Ifuudoudou " and the video is a cover by Shoose of the original.

Following that trail led via [this other video of Shoose's version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o10k8Pem2W4) which gives the info that the original is by [Luka, Miku, Gumi, IA & Rin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43e-5kYEUWY)

Further info on the song :  [page has "explicit themes" warning BTW](http://vocaloidlyrics.wikia.com/wiki/%E5%A8%81%E9%A2%A8%E5%A0%82%E3%80%85_(Ifuudoudou)).